# Child Activity inherits Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a parent Activity holds an `ActionBar` object:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class ParentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

     private ActionBar actionBar; //Action bar

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
         super.onCreate(arg0);
         actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
     }

     public void setActionBar(String title){

        actionBar.setTitle(title);  
    }
}
```

Then, my child Activity inherits the parent Activity, and try to set the `ActionBar` in parent:

```
public class ChildActivity extends ParentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    //try to set action bar title, but get error
    setActionBar(getString(R.string.myname));
        ...
    }
}
```

But I got error:

```
 android.app.SuperNotCalledException
 at ...ParentActivity.setActionBar(..)
```

Then, I changed to use `super.setActionBar(...);`

I got error: `NullPointerException setActionBar`

Why??

Comment: Can you please show the whole stacktrace and post the line of code that throws the exception?

Comment: Also, the content of getSupportActionBar would be nice - can it return null in some cases?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the value of an object which is null, so it shows a null pointer exception. Give the `ActionBar` object some memory the the `new` operator.

```
ActionBar actionbar=new ActiobBar(this);
```